# Creating a program that executes several commands in C

Tags: c, unix, operating-system, system

I am new to System Programming in C.

I would like to write a program that executes several commands, one after one. Commands are separated by semicolon.

Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int counter = 0;
    pid_t fils;

    if (argc == 1){
        printf ("USAGE : who ; pwd ; ls -l\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Number of arguments %d \n",argc);

    for(counter=0;counter<argc;counter++){
        fils = fork();
        if (fils <0){
            perror("Error fork! ");
            exit(1);
        }

        if(fils == 0){
            printf ("Execution of command %d %s \n",counter+1,argv[counter+1]);
            sleep(2);
            execvp(argv[counter+1],argv+counter+1);
        }

        wait(NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For example, my file's name is myProgram, and the list of commands that I wish to execute is : `who ; pwd ; ls -l`

So, when I type : `./myProgram  who ; pwd ; ls -l`
I notice that my program consider only 2 arguments, so it doesn't consider the semicolons. It takes the name of the file as first argument, and the rest as 2nd argument.

How can I modify my code, so that it can consider every command after the semicolon as a separate command by it's own.

Thank you in advance

Comment: It may be in your interest to investigate how the *shell* you're running that command from treats semi-colon separated arguments. Only the first one is actually making it into your `argv[]`. The rest are queued up for execution by the shell itself, as distinct commands.

Comment: @WhozCraig : Thank you for your comment 
 I'm running my program on a simple command line, using Linux as an OS, and as I'm new to System programming, so I don't know to investigate how my shell treats semi-colon. How can I get that please ?

Comment: Semi-colon has a special meaning to the shell. Suggest using a different command seperator.

Comment: See kayfum's comment. There ends the investigation. =P

Comment: @kaylum : Thank you  for youe help

Comment: @WhozCraig : Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

When you type `./myProgram  who ; pwd ; ls -l` the shell interprets this as:

1. run `./myProgram  who`
2. run `pwd`
3. run `ls -l`

But you want to send all of `who ; pwd ; ls -l` as parameters to the single `./myProgram` command, so you need to tell the shell no to interpret `;` as its own separator, like this `./myProgram  who \; pwd \; ls -l`. The special character `\` is used to tell the shell not to interpret the following character but to take it as is.

Comment: Hello, 
Thank you for your answer. 

How can I program the shell so that it won't interpret `;` as its own, please ? 
I'm really new to the programming concept, and I don't know how to tell my shell that :) 

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can't modify your shell like this, it is its own language syntax. Not clear what are your needs...

Comment: I mean it's the user of my program who will type the command line, so we don't know in advance what the user will type as a command line. Maybe `./myProgram who ; ls ` or even maybe `./myProgram pwd; ls -l ` or anything elese ...
So how can I to programm my code so that it will able to return `true` for examle, in case if the last command that it executes goes well.

Comment: if it executes the command `who`, it returns `true`, then if it executes `ls -l`, returns `true`then pass to the next command, else, it should stop. 
The problem here, that I don't know how to code it, so that it returns every time a `true / false` code

Comment: Every process returns an exit code at termination, that you can catch with `wait`. You have passed `NULL`, but if you pass a pointer to an int then you will be able to get the exit statu of the dead process. Read `wait` manual.